# Custom Calendar Date range swipe selection android

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I need to design a custom calendar to choose dates while[image] swiping over them. I need some solution on how to implement swipe on the calendar and also will be helpfull if there are any libraries which support this feature.

Any type of help will be considered. thank you!
The swipe date UI image is as shown

Comment: did you get the solution? if yes plelase assist me

Comment: @TheGreat004 Please refer my accepted answer. Cheers!

Comment: You can check http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-date-range-picker/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As there are many Paid Calendars, I have developed an opensource Unpaid Calendar, which can be used to select dates while swiping over them. Which looks like this[image]

Refer the source code at [SwipeDateCalendar](https://github.com/Sach16/swipedate-calendar)

which also can be further modified as per requirements.

Comment: can u give some idea on how to change the start day from Monday to sunday in your source..?

Comment: I have done what u mentioned  above, but still i not getting. Where i have changed is, GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, lCurrentMonth, 1);cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);

in CalenderActivity in your code.

Comment: @Priya If you have referred [SwipeDateCalendar](https://github.com/Sach16/swipedate-calendar) . I have created an instance of GregorianCalendar. Use that instance and set your preferred first day as shown. `GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1); // changing the value to 0 - starts day from monday changing the value to 1 - starts day from sunday and so on..`

Comment: Hello  Priya , Did your made the calenderview as you wanted as you posted above ?

Answer (score 8):

With the Default Material Components for Android, You can use the new MaterialDatePicker. In which you can get a single date selection as well as date range selection.

add the following to your build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0 alpha02'
```

Call below method for open date range picker

```
private fun setupRangePickerDialog() {
    val builder:MaterialDatePicker.Builder<*> =MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
    val constraintsBuilder = CalendarConstraints.Builder()
    try {
        builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build())
        val picker:MaterialDatePicker<*> =builder.build()
        getDateRange(picker)
        picker.show(supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())
    } catch (e:IllegalArgumentException){
    }
}
```

Now put below method for getting start and end date

```
private fun getDateRange(materialCalendarPicker:MaterialDatePicker<out Any>) {
    materialCalendarPicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener({
            selection:Any ? ->
    Log.e("DateRangeText", materialCalendarPicker.headerText)})
    materialCalendarPicker.addOnNegativeButtonClickListener({
            dialog:View ? ->})
    materialCalendarPicker.addOnCancelListener({
            dialog:DialogInterface ? ->})
}
```

Congrats, You are done!

Answer (score 3):

use this custom calender ,
in build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.savvi.datepicker:rangepicker:1.2.0'
```

and xml file

```
<com.savvi.rangedatepicker.CalendarPickerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:tsquare_dividerColor="@color/calendar_bg"
    app:tsquare_headerTextColor="@color/calendar_selected_day_bg"
    />
```

and java file

```
Calendar pastYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        pastYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, -2);
        Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        nextYear.add(Calendar.DATE,1);



CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView) findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);

    calendar.init(pastYear.getTime(), nextYear.getTime()) //
            .inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.RANGE)
            .withSelectedDate(new Date());
calendar.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
```

https://androidexample365.com/a-calendar-picker-view-to-show-a-customized-date-range-picker-with-improved-ui/

Answer (score 1):

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'
```

use this dependency add to your build.gradle

this is on button click set this code
:

```
 MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long, Long>> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
            CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintsBuilder = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
            builder.setTheme(R.style.CustomThemeOverlay_MaterialCalendar_Fullscreen);
            builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build());
            MaterialDatePicker  picker = builder.build();
            assert getFragmentManager() != null;
            picker.show(getFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

add to into your style.xml:

```
 <style name="CustomThemeOverlay_MaterialCalendar_Fullscreen" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Custom_MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorTextPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="Custom_MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>

</style>
```

add into your whole project style Apptheme this :

```
  <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
```